# String replace with 'any character' mask issue

Tags: javascript, string

I got the string:

```
var x = "341f000k46382000f";
x.replace(/000*/g,"");

i except: x = "341f46382"
```

I want to get replaced `000` +1 character after them. But `*` doesn't works for me.
What syntax i need to use to get `*` works like in windows search ==> * = any character?

Comment: In regex it's `.`, not `*`.

Comment: It should be `x.replace(/000./g,"")`. `*` means *0 or many*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, by adding a `.` to match any character and `{3}` to specifiy 3 `0`s.

```js
const x = "341f000k46382000f"; 
const res = x.replace(/0{3}./g,"");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, yes its dot instead '*'.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression syntax any character is `.` but not `*`.

```js
const x = '341f000k46382000f';
console.log( x.replace(/000./g, '') );
```

**DOCS:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes

Answer (score 1):

You need a dot, for a single character to replace.

```js
var x = "341f000k46382000f";
console.log(x.replace(/000./g,""));
```